# Reorder, exclude a column and keep others in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my toy dataframe:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4), c = c(5, 6), d = c(7, 
8)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I want to reorder and exclude one the columns and keep the others:

```
df %>% select(-a, d, everything())
```

I want my df to be :

```
d b c
7 3 5
8 4 6
```

I get the following:

```
          b     c     d     a
        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1     3     5     7     1
    2     4     6     8     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the `-a` at the last in the `select`.  Even though, we removed `a` in the beginning the `everythig()` at the end is still checking the column names of the whole dataset

```
df%>%
   select(d, everything(), -a)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#      d     b     c
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     7     3     5
#2     8     4     6
```

Comment: Dear akrun, please explain why? Because anything after everything is a "new select"?

Comment: @steves  What I understand is that `everything()` gets all the column names except the ones you already selected. For some reason, it is not checking the deselected column thinking that you want it.  It could be by design to avoid any confusion